# Console not displaying ascii squares correctly

Tags: print-design, font-recommendation, font-design, ascii

I have a 50 x 50 Ascii square (the shape) that I would like to have printed in a console window.

Here is a smaller version of what prints [square (10 x 10)]

```
##########
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
##########
```

I expected that the resulting image would look like a square, not the rectangle above. I thought maybe it had to do with the fonts I was using so I used Monospace fonts thinking that might help but it did not. I also tried different characters thinking that maybe the size of the '.' compared to the '#' was the issue. Again, this was not the case. Even using a single character produced the same results.

Is there a way to achieve that square shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts are not square, even monospace, they are all a vertical rectangle.
On top of this vertical line spacing has to account for (for example) j's and l's which go both above and below the rest.

There is basically no way to do what you are asking without adjusting the vertical and horizontal spacing within the console - which is not possible AFAIK.

Comment: Unless there's a monospace font where the characters are wide enough

Comment: Good thought, unlikely to exist... maybe a custom font...

Comment: +1 That certainly explains it. I appreciate the answer.